# Selecting an intersecting point in a line

Tags: python, selection-tools

Selecting an intersecting point in a line.

Ideally, all points in the line, not just one.

Just for visualization, here is a line.

[image]

And there are the points between the start and end of the line.

[image]

I would like to know how, in Python, if you had selected the points A and B (like in the second image), you were able to select ideally not one (but that would be an acceptable answer for something I could work off of), but all the points (1, 2, 3, and 4) between aforementioned A and B.

The important thing is that A and B are random points in 3D space. They are not flat against the ground (for example with coords 0x, 3y, 0z); but they are always connected as a line.

If someone could help me out here, that would be great. The Blender documentation is unfortunately not as good as Adobe's so I can't do everything (really anything) myself anymore.

Comment: If you are just looking for a tool to select everything between, you can just hold Ctrl when you select the second vertex to select the shortest path between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As HISEROD pointed out, if you click on one vertex to select it, and then hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> before clicking another, you will select the shortest path to that vertex:

[image]

If you indeed need a script solution, here it is:

```
import bpy

index1 = 105
index2 = 165

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj.data.vertices[index1].select = True
obj.data.vertices[index2].select = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select(edge_mode='SELECT', use_fill=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good.